# How to get `setup.cfg` metadata at the command line (Python)

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

When you have a `setup.py` file, you can get the name of the package via the command:

```
C:\some\dir>python setup.py --name
```

And this would print the name of the package to the command line.

In an attempt to adhere to best practice, I'm trying to migrate away from `setup.py` by putting everything in `setup.cfg` since everything that was previously in `setup.py` was static content.

But our build pipeline depends on being able to call `python setup.py --name`. I'm looking to rewrite the pipeline in such a way that I don't need to create a `setup.py` file.

**Is there way to get the name of the package when you have a `setup.cfg` but not a `setup.py` file?**

Comment: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects talks a bit about setup-cfg-only projects emulating a dummy setup.py file that simply runs `setuptools.setup()`.

Explicitly creating a setup.py file that calls a no-arg `setup()` method actually reads the setup.cfg and is enough here to get me the name, but I'm still wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Keeping a minimal `setup.py` is a valid solution. Otherwise use parsing. _setuptools_ uses `ConfigParser` from the standard library to read `setup.cfg`, so as mentioned in an answer this is a valid solution. Soon _setuptools_ should have support for the [_PEP 621_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/) standard which uses TOML format, and a TOML parser will be added to Python's standard library (Python 3.11), so it should be easy to extract info for almost any build back-end (not just _setuptools_).

Comment: If one wants to go one step further and be able to get metadata (name, etc.) from any [_PEP 517_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) project (aka `pyproject.toml`), then it is possible to build some kind of _PEP 517_ "build front-end" just for this purpose and only focus on the [_`prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel()`_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/#prepare-metadata-for-build-wheel) side of things, maybe the [_`pep517`_ library](https://pypi.org/project/pep517/) can help with that.

Comment: [`python -c 'import setuptools; setuptools.setup()' --name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310963)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe using the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) Python module ?

```
python -c "from configparser import ConfigParser; cf = ConfigParser(); cf.read('setup.cfg'); print(cf['metadata']['name'])"
```

Comment: This would cause quite a problem if the desired metadata was the version but you ran into a project declaring `version=attr: my_package.__version__` https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#specifying-values This would be the way to do it, now that I scrolled enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276404/11715259

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR, use the setuptools configuration API** https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuration-api.

In your case, this line will give the name of the package:

```sh
python -c 'from setuptools.config import read_configuration as c; print(c("setup.cfg")["metadata"]["name"])'
```

---

**Edit:**

In setuptools v61.0.0 (24 Mar 2022) [`setuptools.config.read_configuration` was deprecated](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v61-0-0) . Using the new API, the command becomes:

```sh
python -c 'from setuptools.config.setupcfg import read_configuration as c; print(c("setup.cfg")["metadata"]["name"])'
```

---

**Explanation:**

Setuptools exposes a `read_configuration()` function for parsing metadata and options sections of the configuration. Internally, setuptools uses the `configparser` module to parse the configuration file `setup.cfg`. For simple `str`-type data such as the "name" key, configparser can be used to read the data. However, setuptools also allows [dynamic configuration using directives](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#specifying-values) that cannot be directly parsed with configparser.

Here is an example that shows the difference between the two approaches for replacing `python setup.py --version`:

```
$ tree .
.
├── my_package
│   └── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg

1 directory, 3 files

$ cat setup.cfg
[metadata]
name = my_package
version = attr:my_package.__version__

[options]
packages = find:

$ cat my_package/__init__.py 
__version__ = "1.0.0"

$ cat pyproject.toml

$ python -c 'from setuptools.config import read_configuration as c; print(c("setup.cfg")["metadata"]["version"])'
1.0.0

$ python -c 'from configparser import ConfigParser; c = ConfigParser(); c.read("setup.cfg"); print(c["metadata"]["version"])'
attr:my_package.__version__
```

Comment: _Note:_ If you use a `pyproject.toml` (with `setuptools.build_meta` backend) then you wouldn't necessarily have a `setup.cfg` file to parse at all, project name and version would be specified in the TOML ([PEP621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)). Then this approach fails, but the simpler `python -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup()' --name` and `python3 -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup()' --version` should continue to work in any case.

Answer (score 4):

For an "over-kill" solution that allows getting any meta-data field from any [*PEP 517*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/)-compatible project (i.e. `pyproject.toml`), with the help of the [*`build`* project](https://pypi.org/project/build/):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import pathlib

import build.util

def _main():
    args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args_parser.add_argument('path')
    args = args_parser.parse_args()
    path_name = getattr(args, 'path')
    path = pathlib.Path(path_name)
    #
    metadata = build.util.project_wheel_metadata(path)
    print(metadata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

This will actually call the build back-end (*setuptools*, *poetry*, *flit*, *pdm*, or watever), so this might take some seconds.

The `build.util` API is documented [here (on "*latest*")](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-build.util) and it was added in ["0.7.0 (16-09-2021)"](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id3), in this [change](https://github.com/pypa/build/pull/340).

---

But yes, realistically, as you have already said it I would recommend just keeping a minimal `setup.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```

so that `python setup.py --name` keeps working

And of course, as others have already said it, parsing is a viable and simple solution. *setuptools* uses [*`ConfigParser`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) from the standard library to read the *`setup.cfg`* file, so you can do it as well.

---

Another possible solution ([credit to wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310963)):

```
python -c 'import setuptools; setuptools.setup()' --name
```

Comment: Unlike my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71693117/11715259, this WILL work despite the build backend not implementing the optional `prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel` hook. Nice! Too bad build.util won't show in the project API documentation.

Comment: @N1ngu It is [here (on "_latest_")](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-build.util), confusing... it was added in ["0.7.0 (16-09-2021)"](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id3), in this [change](https://github.com/pypa/build/pull/340).