# Get python3 package metadata given source directory without installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to get some package metadata (name, version) given a path to the source directory without installing said package.

These work, using `setup.py` if you're sitting in the root directory:

```sh
> python3 setup.py --name
my_package_name

> python3 setup.py --version
0.1.0
```

However, I have been cautioned away from using `python3 setup.py` commands -- and indeed see a warning:

```
.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
  SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
```

I know `pip show my_package_name` will print various metadata about a package (including name/version), however it requires that the package is installed into the environment. It also doesn't take a source directory and thus requires I already know the name of the package I want the info on.

```sh
> pip show .
WARNING: Package(s) not found: .

> pip show my_package_name
WARNING: Package(s) not found: my_package_name

> pip install .
...

> pip show my_package_name
Name: my_package_name
Version: 0.1.0
...
...
```

Is there any equivalent `pip` command (or other tool) that will show me the version of a package given the source directory without actually installing the package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is might be a big workaround, but it should work as long as the html name doesn't change... for a stable long-term solution this is not ideal.
`version_check() { wget -O - https://pypi.org/project/${1} 2>&1 | grep package-header__name -A 1 | tail -1 | xargs ; }` Running `version_check package_name` should provide the name and version without needing to download the whole package

But surely there should be a more reliable way?

Comment: @ScottMastro Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately these packages aren't on a pypi repository (at least, not the 'global' `pypi.org`). I only have the source code, e.g. what you'd get after cloning the project from git.

Comment: I found `from pip._vendor.pep517.meta import load; data = load(".")`. Version and name are `data.version` and `data.name`, all other metadata can be found using `vars(data.metadata)`. This basically uses the build system to generate the metadata: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/?highlight=metadata#metadata-generation

Comment: Have you explored [poetry](https://python-poetry.org) as an alternative package manager? pip can sometimes be a pain in the back

Comment: @Olamide226 I'm not sure if its so much a `pip` vs `poetry` here. I think in my case we'd replace `setuptools` (e.g. `setup.py`) with `poetry`. But AFAIK you'd still use pip for many things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276197

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get \`setup.cfg\` metadata at the command line (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271825/how-to-get-setup-cfg-metadata-at-the-command-line-python)

Comment: @sinoroc not necessarily, as some packages still use setup.py for some metadata. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: @wakey There is absolutely nothing wrong with calling `python setup.py --version` if you have a `setup.py`. -- There are two things... ***1.*** The commands `setup.py install`, `setup.py sdist`, etc. are deprecated and they have replacements. But this does not mean you have to change anything to your project's files. ***2.*** It is strongly recommended to modernize your packaging  in order to adhere to the newest standards (add a `pyproject.toml`, remove the `setup.py`, etc.). But if it is not possible, then so be it. There is nothing wrong with calling `python setup.py --version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pip -v install` together with [`--global-option="--version"`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-global-option). According to [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides) this will translate in the following way:

```
python -m pip -v install --global-option="--version" path/to/project
```

is equivalent to

```
python setup.py --version install
```

The latter command just runs the `--version` part and then exits, thus ignoring the `install` part. Since the corresponding subprocess terminates successfully, `pip` will report it has installed the package when it actually didn't. Anyway, the third line from the bottom will contain the output from the `setup.py` call, i.e. the version number:

```
Processing ./path/to/project
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  running egg_info
  [...]
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Skipping wheel build for testpkg, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: testpkg
  Running command Running setup.py install for testpkg
  1.2
  Running setup.py install for testpkg ... done
Successfully installed testpkg
```

---

**Note:** This is probably a hacky solution as it relies on the printed output of `pip -v install` which might change for future releases. Anyway, it works for the current version of pip (22.0.4).

Comment: I fear that will specifically not work in the absence of a setup.py file, which is what the reported warning is about. That is: won't work for any project using poetry, flit, the pure-pep-517 setuptools.build_meta or any other pep-517 build backend.

Comment: @N1ngu Sure, but in those cases, there are other solutions. From the question I got the impression that this is *specifically* about projects using `setup.py`; at least they indicated they could do `python3 setup.py --version` if it wasn't deprecated.

Comment: Then this just hides the warning in a very convoluted way, does not fix anything about it! Better use `python -Wignore setup.py --whatever`.

Comment: @N1ngu It doesn't *hide* the warning, it *prevents* it in the first place. The point of the deprecation warning is that `setuptools` doesn't want to provide a command line interface anymore (see e.g. [this blog post](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html)). It might seem weird to *still* access part of its CLI via `--global-option="--version"`, but the key difference here is that you get a promise from `pip` that this does what you expect it to do (even if `setup.py --version` stops working in the future; it's up to `pip` to handle this correctly).

Comment: sorry to disagree. This just forwards the option to the build backend https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#config-settings but pip has no way of knowing what it means nor can guarantee any kind of behavior. What pip understands is that you have custom building needs, so it will discard wheels and go for sdist installs. But only `setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__` will do something with the `--version` option. Any other backend will omit it and install the package right away. The only way to *prevent* such a warning is to stop using the deprecated interface. This just hides it.

Comment: @N1ngu Following PEP-517, `pip` as a frontend makes sure that the backend receives the `config_settings` in the appropriate way; that's the promise you get from `pip`. `pip` knows how to speak to the legacy interface of `setuptools` and it will stop providing these options once they are dropped (see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/setup-py/#customising-the-build)). Regarding the suggestion to *"stop using the deprecated interface"*, this makes perfectly sense if possible, but as I understood the question, it was specifically concerned with projects using `setup.py`.

Comment: To my understanding the main concern of the question is due to the warning, which is about setup.py not existing. I guess that's the root of our disagreement. If setup.py could be ensured to exist in your projects, the warning could be ignored altogether, no need for any workaround nor new method to extract metadata!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't as compact as the setup.py calls, but you can use the `pep517` package.

`python  -m pep517.meta  my-package` will create a my-package/dist/my_package.dist-info/METADATA file where you can read all the available info.

`pip` vendors this PyPA library so `python  -m pip._vendor.pep517.meta  my-package` should work without additional installs.

**Caveat**

This will only work if the PEP-517 build backend has implemented the `prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel` hook, which is optional according to https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#prepare-metadata-for-build-wheel

Lets see if someone comes up with a better tool.

---

If you ever run on a pure PEP-517 project using the setuptools.build_meta backend that lacks a setup.py file, you can still create an "empty" one (with the following content)

```
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

and keep using the `python setup.py` instructions.

BUT this won't work for other PEP-517 build backends like poetry or flit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276197