# Makefile - How should I extract the version number embedded in `pyproject.toml`?

Tags: python, makefile, pyproject.toml

I have a python project with a `pyproject.toml` file. Typically I store the project's version number in `pyproject.toml` like this:

```
% grep version pyproject.toml 
version = "0.0.2"
%
```

I want to get that version number into a `Makefile` variable regardless of how many spaces wind up around the version terms.

What should I do to extract the `pyproject.toml` version string into a `Makefile` environment variable called `VERSION`?

Comment: You could follow this (heavy but accurate) approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution to parse `major.minor.patch`, based on [@Mike Pennington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667301/mike-pennington)'s answer:

```
grep -m 1 version pyproject.toml | grep -e '\d.\d.\d' -o
```

Comment: `grep -e '\d.\d.\d' -o` is a good addition

Answer (score 7):

This seemed to work out the best...  I put this in my `Makefile`

```
# grep the version from pyproject.toml, squeeze multiple spaces, delete double
#   and single quotes, get 3rd val. This command tolerates 
#   multiple whitespace sequences around the version number
VERSION := $(shell grep -m 1 version pyproject.toml | tr -s ' ' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'" | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

Special thanks to [@charl-botha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592060/makefile-how-should-i-extract-the-version-number-embedded-in-pyproject-toml/72545515#comment128150232_71592061) for the `-m 1` grep argument... both gnu and bsd grep support `-m` in this context.

Comment: This will break if there are multiple "version =" statements in the file, e.g. in additional dependency version constraints further down. Use `-m 1` argument to grep to use only the first occurrence.

Comment: I just ran into this: `uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "^0.17.6"}` -- which necessitated the `-m 1` in our case. HTH?

Comment: The `-m 1` option also ONLY works if the first occurence is the correct one. If you have a comment or anything else mentioning "version" before the actual version this approach still fails.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Python available with the tomli package installed, or you're on Python 3.11 with toml built-in (in which case you would `import tomllib` instead of `tomli`), and your `pyproject.toml` follows poetry convention, something like the following would work well:

```
VERSION := $(shell python -c 'import tomli; print(tomli.load(open("pyproject.toml", "rb"))["tool"]["poetry"]["version"])')
```

Test on command-line with simply:

```
python -c 'import tomli; print(tomli.load(open("pyproject.toml", "rb"))["tool"]["poetry"]["version"])'
```

Obviously you can easily adapt the location of the desired `version` entry in the case of other `pyproject.toml` conventions.

BTW, `tomllib` is in fact `tomli`, see https://peps.python.org/pep-0680/#rationale

Answer (score 1):

If that's all that file really contains, that's sufficiently close to makefile syntax that you can just include it as a makefile:

```
include pyproject.toml
all: ; echo 'version = $(version)'

$ make
echo 'version = "0.0.2"'
version = "0.0.2"
```

If you don't want to, or can't, do that, I'd use `sed` for it:

```
VERSION := $(shell sed -n 's/^ *version.*=.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' pyproject.toml)
all: ; echo 'version = $(VERSION)'

$ make
echo 'version = 0.0.2'
version = 0.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that include was a slick way to get `pyproject.toml` variables into a `Makefile`, but `make` choked when it hit this line: `[tool.poetry]`... it dumped me into the `bash` prompt.  I think grepping the version out is probably better.

Comment: As I said, if that line you quoted is the ONLY line in the file, then it will work.  If there's other lines in the file, that don't match makefile syntax (such as `[tool.poetry]`) then include won't work.

Comment: I wasn’t completely sure what you meant at the time, but please understand that ‘pyproject.toml’ requires section headings in brackets… the config is useless without section headers.

Comment: Yes, so, the `include` option won't work in that situation.