# Obtain the version of a setup.cfg package

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

When using `setup.py` in a Python project, we can simply run

```
$ python3 setup.py --version
```

And this will give us the `version` field that is set in the `setup.py` file. This saves us using `sed` or something alike to read the version when we need to do so in a script.

I was wondering, is there an equivalent way in a `setup.cfg` project?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71271825

Answer (score 3):

When you have only a `setup.cfg`, and no `setup.py` file, you can do this:

```
$ cat setup.cfg
[metadata]
name = mypkg
version = "0.1.2.3"  # or `file: VERSION.txt` or `attr: mypkg.__version__` etc

$ python3 -c 'import setuptools; setuptools.setup()' --version
"0.1.2.3"
```

If the build backend is setuptools, then this approach will also work for a [source tree](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/source-distribution-format/?highlight=517#source-trees) with a `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: This works for a `pyproject.toml` file as well.

Answer (score -1):

Allow me to deviate from your actual question to offer what I thing is a better solution.

If you have to get the package version while developing (from an outside script) then you should split such information from your `setup.cfg`/`setup.py`.

You want `setup.cfg` (i.e, setuptools) to get that information from a file, for instance. Then, you can have the version just by reading the corresponding file.

Check the docs for details: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html. Notice the [`#meta-1`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#meta-1) anchor/note in that page.

Basically, you'll use `attr` or `file` attributes (in your `setup.cfg` metadata section) to get the version from another place:

```
version = file: VERSION.txt
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (_"to read the version when we need to do so in a script"_), and besides, the advice is outdated anyway.

Comment: @wim how come is outdated?

Comment: No matter whether version metadata is defined statically or dynamically, doing it in `pyproject.toml` is the modern way, not in random other files. See [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#version).

Comment: @wim works pretty well for me. By all means, thanks for the update.