# Is there a way to extract project metadata without Pip-installing it?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pep517

I am developing a project using Setuptools, and in a couple of places (e.g. scripts, the Sphinx docs) I want to be able to use pieces of project metadata, such as the version, name, authors, etc. I want to avoid hard-coding these values, as they are all subject to change.

I am using `pyproject.toml` to define metadata containing some `dynamic` values, and I also have a `setup.py` that builds some Cython extensions.

I am aware that `importlib.metadata` gives you access to metadata of *installed* distributions, but for team-specific reasons I cannot necessarily assume that my project is installed into any particular environment.

I also want to avoid manually parsing `pyproject.toml` and ad-hoc reimplementing the Setuptools logic.

Does Setuptools have a stable Python API for this purpose?

Ideally I would be able to pass a directory (maybe just `'.'`) to some function, and get a `distutils.core.Distribution` that I can work with and get information from, which contains the metadata extracted from `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg`, and/or `setup.py`.

Comment: There are third party libraries that parse the pyproject.toml - arguably they have done what you wanted to avoid doing (and I think that's wise), but since the work has already been done and may be maintained, it could still be your best option at this point? And that's assuming the [3.11 `tomllib`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/tomllib.html) is either too distant future, or doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: @Grismar I am hoping to avoid a DIY ad-hoc reimplementation of a subset of Setuptools. Grabbing static values from the TOML file is the easy part.

Comment: Some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276197

Comment: @sinoroc that might constitute an answer, thank you. Using `build` is interesting because it should abstract over _all_ build backends, not just Setuptools. I will try this and report back!

Comment: Yes, this will work for any "PEP 517"-based project, even for "dynamic" metadata fields. But this is a "heavy" solution, it will do a lot of computation (including installing the build back-end dependencies in an ephemeral virtual environment).